# Splitting data in SQL based on spaces for names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where I need to split "First Name" and "Last Name" based upon spaces. Names can have 3 to 4 spaces in between.
Example:

```
|Full Name|
-----------
|A B C    |
|A B C D  |
-----------

Expected Output
-------------
|FirstName | LastName |
-----------------------
|B C       | A        |
|C D       | A B      |
```

I am able to split the first row using below query:

```
select Substring ('A B C', Charindex( ' ', 'A B C') + 1,  
Len('A B C')) as FirstName;
select SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM('A B C')),1,CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(RTRIM('A B C')))-1) as lastName;
```

I am using SQL Server as a database.

I am not sure how to split the second row.

Can someone please help me with SQL query to handle this more effectively because the Full Name can have both types of spaces in between tokens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please tag the RDBMS you are using ? and show us your attempts ?

Comment: Please update your question with a comprehensive set of business rules describing how to split the column - presumably based on the number of characters, number of spaces, etc

Comment: that means all people have exact 2 "first" names? Strange

Comment: I have some names to add to your sample data, Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien, Carl van der Walt, Jonathan Rhys-Davies, Catherine Zeta-Jones, Sammy Davies Jr. and George W Bush.

Comment: These are Chinese names, and they may have 2 words in last name and first names.

Comment: Split the data *before* inserting it in the database. SQL is a query language, not a text manipulation language. Never mind that what you ask may require machine learning algorithms like entity recognition, which *does* recognize names, addresses etc (entities) in a phrase.

Comment: Oblig: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: On the other hand, SQL Server's [Machine Learning Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/sql-server-machine-learning-services?view=sql-server-ver16) in SQL Server 2017 and later include a Python environment with the most popular data science packages, which probably includes entity recognition. You may be able to write a small Python script to extract the name parts and apply it to the existing data with `sp_execute_external_script`

Comment: At the very least try a Named Entity Recognizer package like SpaCy in Python to see what can be achieved. You may have to find a NER package trained in Chinese names though.

Comment: You might have better focus by describing your requirement not for names but just in terms of parsing a delimited string, thus not opening a very large can of worms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure there are 2, 3 or 4 tokens, you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT  '"' + RIGHT(name, ss.second_space - 1) + '"' AS first_name
,   '"' + LEFT(name, LEN(name) - ss.second_space) + '"' AS last_name
,   name
FROM    (
    SELECT  'Alice Bob' AS name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  N'A B C'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  'A B C D'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  'Alice Bob Candy Daniel'
    ) x
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT  ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(name), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(name)) + 1), 0), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(name))) AS second_space
    ) ss
```

You find the second space from the right which will be the first name, and then you take RIGHT(second_space) or LEFT(length - second_space) to fetch the names.

I added quotes "" around names so it's easier to see if there are any spaces. Output:

| first_name | last_name | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "Bob" | "Alice" | Alice Bob |
| "B C" | "A" | A B C |
| "C D" | "A B" | A B C D |
| "Candy Daniel" | "Alice Bob" | Alice Bob Candy Daniel |

Comment: That's what I was actually looking for, thanks a bunch for your help. Could you please also share some code if the full name is like 'A B' and output should have first name = 'B' and last name = 'A' ?

Comment: Added a new version, but you're not really supposed to ask follow-up questions :)

Comment: @user3204086 can you edit your question and include this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `STRING_SPLIT` :

```
WITH cte as (
  SELECT *, (sum(1) over(PARTITION BY full_name) - ordinal)/2 as grp 
  FROM mytable
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(full_name, ' ', 1)
)
SELECT full_name, STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN grp = 0 THEN value END, ' ') as  first_name,
                  STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN grp = 1 THEN value END, ' ') as  last_name
FROM cte
GROUP BY full_name
```

Separating names according to the required logic will be made easier by using some aggregation based on `(sm-ordinal)/2`.

Result :

```
full_name   first_name  last_name
A B C       B C         A
A B C D     C D         A B
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/8s-pfUJ1)